# How to return diff data from an Ansible action plugin

Tags: python, ansible

I'm writing an Ansible module implemented as an action plugin, similar to the Template module and plugin provided with the core of Ansible. I'd like to return diff data with before and after lines as a module would do. I can find examples of how to return this data from an actual module, but I'm stuck trying to extrapolate how to associate the same information with the return from an action plugin.

In the `lineinfile` module, diff data is returned as the diff keyword parameter in the call to `module.exit_json()`, like so:

```py
module.exit_json(changed=changed, msg=msg, backup=backupdest, diff=difflist)
```

However, it appears that no plug-ins ever call `exit_json()`, nor could they, because they don't have a `module` data structure to work with.

The `exit_json()` method on `module` appears to be defined on [line 2042 of `module_utils/basic.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/89b73cb5355930b64a90b67402c98b8964f2855d/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L2042) It calls, in turn, `self._return_formatted()` on [line 2007](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/89b73cb5355930b64a90b67402c98b8964f2855d/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L2007), which appears to echo `kwargs` (after some clean-up) to `stdout`. So . . . just add a `diff` keyword to the existing `result` structure? I'll play with that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, adding a `diff` keyword and value to the existing `result` dict returned from the plugin appears to be sufficient. Here is an incomplete, minimalist example:

```py
class ActionModule(ActionBase):
    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):

        diff = {'before': 'old data\n',
                'after': 'new data\n'}

        result['diff'] = diff
        result['changed'] = True

        return result
```